# homomorphic encryption and DARPA

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption

Why the government (and the DARPA in particular)is spending all these millions to improve the homomorphic encryption?which useful usage could it get?

Comment: Which millions? Please provide which projects you are speaking about. One interesting project is this one [here](http://sharemind.cyber.ee/news-blog/estonian-company-cybernetica-develops-secure-data-computation-technology-for-us-government). Please, be more specific.

Answer (score 11):

In one sentence: data can be modified and calculated without being disclosed. Quoting from the Wikipedia page: *... effectively allowing the construction of programs which may be run on encryptions of their inputs to produce an encryption of their output. Since such a program never decrypts its input, it can be run by an untrusted party without revealing its inputs and internal state.*

Like with most research agencies, their possible benefits aren't fully described. The full benefits of GPS, for example, were probably not imagined at the time either.

Comment: Wow. Really? Wow! The more I learn about cryptography, the more it just blows me away!!

Answer (score 0):

Homomorphic encryption is important for more than one reason.

However, the situations where I'm aware of its direct value is for self-modifying code e.g. packers and further protection of self-integrity-checking code. In other words, it's useful for software protection and potentially DRM.